# the text of a notetaking activity starts behind the app bar

Tags: android, android-studio, appbar, behind

The app works good, except for the fact that when I enter some notes, the first note disappears behind the app bar.
How can I start that part from under the app bar?

3 notes, only 2 visible
[image: 3 notes, only 2 visible]

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Notities">



    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cb_color="@color/primary"
    app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
    android:minWidth="64dp"
    android:minHeight="64dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_notities"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--<Button-->
<!--android:id="@+id/button"-->
<!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
<!--android:layout_alignParentRight="true"-->
<!--android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"-->
<!--android:text="New note" />-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`DrawerLayout`](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and [`AppBar`](http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html) both seem to be set up incorrectly. Your `DrawerLayout` should only contain two children, one for the main content and one for the drawer content. The drawer content should be below the main content in your XML, and the `layout_width` for the drawer content should probably be a set dimension, usually `240dp`. Something like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include android:id="@+id/content_frame" layout="@layout/content_frame"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width_nav_drawer" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/drawer_main"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then your `AppBar` should be placed in a `CoordinatorLayout` in your `content_frame`, with your main content (your `ListView`) placed below:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlsn:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toobar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:backgroud="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include android:id="@+id/content_main" layout="@layout/content_main"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And finally your `ListView` (or `RecyclerView`) can be placed in any kind of layout you choose (I chose a `FrameLayout` here):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Also, if you noticed, I included the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in my `FrameLayout`. This is important as it sets the behavior of the `AppBarLayout` and how it should react to your `FrameLayout`. Basically, it makes it so the view is below the `AppBar`, and can scroll if necessary.

---

**Side Note:**

I also noticed you are using the `at.markushi.ui.CircleButton` from an external library. This library was created before Google introduced the support library including the Floating Action Button, and is now [`deprecated`](https://github.com/markushi/android-circlebutton). Since Google has introduced the new [`FloatingActionButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html), you can use it in your `CoordinatorLayout` as the last element:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/btn_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_standard" android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_white_24dp"
    android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the `ToolBar` and `ListView` in a `RelativeLayout` and give `layout_below` property to the `ListView` so that it comes below the `ToolBar`.
Something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".Notities">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_notities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/android:list"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cb_color="@color/primary"
            app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
            android:onClick="openEditorForNewNote"
            android:minWidth="64dp"
            android:minHeight="64dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: This in not best practice, and may lead to unexpected results. If acting as an `ActionBar`, the `Toolbar` should be placed in an `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`, documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

Comment: @Bryan Thanks for the feedback. Will try to improve. :)